# 5×5 dimensional matrix from m×n matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, list, dry, sublist

I have got a m×n dimensional matrix, I need to get 5×5 dimensional matrix by indexes `i`, `j`. Result should be like this:

```
res = [[arr[i-2][j-2], arr[i-2][j-1]], arr[i-2][j  ], arr[i-2][j+1], arr[i-2][j+2]]
       [arr[i-1][j-2], arr[i-1][j-1]], arr[i-1][j  ], arr[i-1][j+1], arr[i-1][j+2]],
       [arr[i  ][j-2], arr[i  ][j-1]], arr[i  ][j  ], arr[i  ][j+1], arr[i  ][j+2]],
       [arr[i+1][j-2], arr[i+1][j-1]], arr[i+1][j  ], arr[i+1][j+1], arr[i+1][j+2]],
       [arr[i+2][j-2], arr[i+2][j-1]], arr[i+2][j  ], arr[i+2][j+1], arr[i+2][j+2]]]
```

The problem is array's indexes. `i`, `j` are random numbers, so it can be `0, 0` or `m-1, n-1`. In this case problematic values like `[arr[i-2][j-2]` or `[arr[i+2][j+2]` must be replaced with `'x'`. Is there any dry way to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like that would do the work :

```
def give_matrix(arr,i,j):
    res = []
    for ii in range(i-2,i+3): 
        inner_res = []
        for jj in range(j-2,j+3):
            if (ii-2<0 or ii+3>n or jj-2<0 or jj+3>n): # manage borders
                inner_res.append('x')
            else:
                inner_res.append(arr[ii][jj])
        res.append(inner_res)
    return res
```

**[Livecode](https://ideone.com/QzgY6m)**

Comment: Thanks, but I edited the question. i, j can be 0. That's the problem.

Comment: Ok I updated the answer to manage the borders ! But you won't get a 5*5 matrix so... Is this what you want ?

Comment: no, what i want is in this case the replacement with 'x' and still 5*5 dimension

Comment: well you can work a little bit on that... And I find that poor design... a character mixed with values ??? Why would you need that ? Is that homework ? :/

Comment: yes, it's a frog and fly game. And fly standing on i,j should see only 5*5 part  of the matris.

Comment: Ok I updated the answer with a livecode. But next time try to tell us what you have done.

Comment: Well you should show what you have tried so far and that you have put some efforts. If my answer is ok for you you can validate by checking it. Welcome on SO !

Comment: i was checking index by index. It's very useful but not working properly Im working on it. The results are not correct : print(give_matrix(1,10)) and  print(give_matrix(8,19))

Comment: with few changes I think it's gonna work. Thanks for your time @coincoin